# Extracting version number substring

Tags: sed, grep, substring, vmware-workstation

I have this:

```
Product Name         Product Version     
==================== ====================
vmware-workstation   9.0.2.1031769
```

I can get the `vmware-workstation` part with a:

```
$ vmware-installer -l | grep -Po "(?=v)[^ ]*(?= )"
```

How do I get the version number part (without the build, meaning just `9.0.2`)?

Comment: `(\d+\.)+\d+` and then use only the capture group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it with grep:

`vmware-installer -l | grep -Po "(\d+\.){2}\d+"`

Comment: Real winners don't use capture groups when not needed

Comment: @sputnick, why you getting so upset? It's just slightly simpler and works in this particular situation, lol.

Comment: upset ? Mhhh... The goal of stackexchange web sites are not to reply to a particular need of someone but to be as universal as possible. Capturing when not necessary is useless. This is [reusability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reusability)

Comment: I was going for readability. Didn't mean to ruffle any feathers. :)

Comment: @sputnick, and that's good but it wasn't what I was looking for here.

Comment: The parentheses define an expression used with the {} operator. They're not just for capturing.

Comment: @sputnick oh, I get it now... Does that mean you write all your command line regex with "?:" whenever groups are involved. Wow!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ vmware-installer -l | grep -Po "^v\S+\s+\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
9.0.2

$ vmware-installer -l | grep -Po "(?:\d+\.){2}\d+"
9.0.2
```

this :

```
(?:)
```

avoid not needed capturing groups

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
vmware-installer -l | sed -n 's/[^ ]* *\(.*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/p'
```